# How to fix getBound method in java?

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection

[image]

this is simple java game and it contains craft.java and wall.java class.All red line in picture is object of wall class

```
public void buildWall(){

        walls.add(new Wall(10,10,getWidth()-10, 10));
        walls.add(new Wall(10,10,10,getHeight()-10));
        walls.add(new Wall(10,getHeight()-10,getWidth()-10,getHeight()-10));
        walls.add(new Wall(getWidth()-10, getHeight()-10, getWidth()-10, 10));
        walls.add(new Wall(100, 10, 100, 50));
        walls.add(new Wall(150, 10, 150, 50));

    }
```

and i write a getBound2D() method for define the lines

```
public Wall(int x, int y , int z , int v){

         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.z = z;
         this.v = v;
         vis = true;

         line = new Line2D.Double(x,y,z,v);
     }

    @Override
    public Rectangle2D getBounds2D() {
        return new Rectangle(x,y,z,v);
    }
```

but this method is not working correctly. My purpose is when aircraft is touch the any one of line check collision and will game over . How should i fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line has its own getBounds so you can use that:

it has getBounds() and getBounds2D();

the width of a vertical line is zero and the height of a horizontal line is zero.

```
System.out.println(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 0, 100).getBounds()+" "+new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 0).getBounds2D());
```

To have your vertical/horizontal lines have width/height 1 you can define it so:

```
getBounds2D() {
  return new Rectangle(x, y, z-x+1, v-y+1);
}
```

Comment: actually i need a dynamic getBound method because all lines have different start point and different long